# Google source repository integration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-source-repositories

I have a git repository with multiple branches which I wanted to push to google source repository. But it takes only a particular branch of the repository. How can I create a branch on google source repository and push code to that branch only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

edit, add and commit your files.

then push the branch to the remote:

```
git push -u origin branch_name
```

assuming you have already added it as remote.

see [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) & [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).